# Mysql/Mysqli/PDO Performance - The number of tables or tables I print

Tags: mysql, performance, pdo, query-performance

I am using **PDO**, I would like to know How many columns in a table is fine? I will not retrive all of it once but I am thinking to store many columns in a single table, and I will retrive just the necessary columns, Is there a performance problem If I do this way or I can do it just fine?

What about the PDO is the performance affected by the number of tables I have or the number of tables I print in php?

Comment: `MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table` but obviously less columns the better. also its common choice to store blob/text data in separate tables

Comment: What about the PDO is the performance affected by the number of tables I have or the number of tables I print in php?

Comment: `PDO` is a wrapper around a driver. MySQL uses textual protocol. The more data you send, the more time it takes to parse that text. Whether you shave off 500 microseconds here or there - what does it matter? It's not `PDO` that will cause you problems with a lot of data, it's network speed, buffering speed and memory that will have to be spent. You're optimizing at wrong place. You design data model so you can query and hold the data, not to have it work fast with `PDO` or <insert name here>. It seems you got it backwards.

Comment: This question is over generalized. Yes, design decisions have performance impacts. But the number of columns in a table is not usually the big rock in terms of performance. In addition to the limit on the number of columns, InnoDB also imposes a maximum row size just shy of 64K. First, get the data model normalized. Get the entities, relationships and attributes into a workable model. Consider the constraints that will need to be enforced, and what operations/transactions will need to be performed, and concurrency. Sometimes it is appropriate to break a single entity into two or more tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1017 in InnoDB.

But, more than 100 is getting into the area of "bad schema design".

You can use `JOIN` to stitch together multiple tables.

What are the columns like?  `phone1`, `phone2`, ... `phone11`?  If so, do *not* play them (or any other array) across columns.  That *is* bad schema design.

There is not a max row size of 64KB.  The limit there is more complex.

[*Various Hard limits*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits) .

Getting "all the columns" at once is *usually* poor design.  (Oh, dear, am I repeating myself?)